# How to correctly close a c# form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am currently working with a c# desktop application that is connected to a web service. In one of the forms, I want to close form when the back button is clicked. I have done it like this:

```
private void bBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this.Hide();
    this.Close();
    frmMain fMain = new frmMain();
    fMain.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    fMain.Show();
}
```

When I use `this.Hide()`, it seems like the form I want to close still runs in the background, thus still contacting the web service.

When I use `this.Close()`, the form seems to close and no contact to the web service is made, but my desktop application suddenly goes full screen and `frmMain` is opened in a new window.

I have read the documentation displayed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close(v=vs.110).aspx), but I could not find anything useful.

Comment: thats because hide just hides it.. it is still running in the background.   Your code here shows nothing of a webservice, but try making the main new form before closing this one.

Comment: the more I read this question the more unclear it becomes. Please clarify what your issue is. It seems the first 2 thirds of this question are irrlevant ot what you actually want and the question you actually want asking *but my desktop application suddenly goes full screen and frmMain() is opened in a new window.* contains no code. But even that is very, very unclear. **What is the question?**

Comment: @BugFinder i didn't include the ws implementation because it worked fine. Anyways I followed your advice and it looks like it works. I just thought in order to show the frmMain() you needed to close the existing form first.

Comment: @noel great - ive added it as an answer so you can give it the big hurrah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide does just that, it hides it, its still there.

So yes, you would need to close it, however, if you close it before you make the next, theres a chance that the code exits there and isnt completing any follow on code.

Rearranging your code to

```
frmMain fMain = new frmMain();
fMain.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
fMain.Show();
this.Close();
```

Should work

Comment: Why assign `MdiParent` when you can assign `Parent` directly?

Comment: I just rearranged his code .. yes you can set parent.. but this is the MDIparent, I havent used mdi in a while so left his code as was..

Comment: `MdiParent` is the correct property to set, setting `fMain.Parent` on a form throws an exception. Perhaps @CamiloTerevinto meant to ask "why copy from `this.MdiParent`"? But as we don't have the OP's code, ...

Comment: @C.Evenhuis No, it doesn't throw any exception, who told you that? I assign `Parent` in many projects.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto "Top-level control cannot be added to a control." Are you sure you're talking about assigning a value to a `Form.Parent`?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Yes, I always do `new WhateverForm().Parent = this;` (where `this` refers to the calling `Form`)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I stand corrected, it is possible - but I still have to explicitly set `form.TopLevel = false` first to prevent the exception, and that's also what the `MdiParent` property does under the hood.